# getKerberosTGT() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serverName'

Tags: impacket

When I used getTGT.py, it prompted me error.[gettgt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfgjH.png)
And when I used GetUserSPNs.py, it appeared again.[getuserspn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k69kq.png)[getkercode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjptG.png)[gettgtcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAm0e.png)[getuseerspncode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ghTn.png)

I think they come from the same problem. But I have never changed the files in Impacket. At the same time, I have repeatedly checked and found no problems. It cannot be a problem caused by parameters.So I can't understand where the problem lies.I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. I really hope someone can tell me how to solve this problem.I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Don't include your code as an image, include it as code block.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved after updating the Impacket